# How to validate a field based on another model data

Tags: mysql, node.js, validation, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to validate a date field based on information stored in the database through another model.

When I test the api, validation works correctly throwing the exception, **however, the insertion occurs before this exception**. That is, it does not prevent the insertion in thedatabase. Where I went wrong?

This is my validate function:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Step = sequelize.define('Step', {
  ...
  resultDate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    validate: {
      isEven(value){
        sequelize.models.Call
          .findById(this.call_id)
          .then(call => {
            if(value >= call.endingDate) throw new Error('Error message here!');
          });
  ...
```

And this is the result:

```
Executing (default): SELECT [...] `Call`.`id` = '19c7e81e-5c23-4fd5-8623-0170deee6cd4');
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Steps` [...];
Unhandled rejection Error message here!
```

Clearly, the initial SELECT is to perform validation, however, before the validation quit and throw the exception, the API inserts into the database and returns success already!

**How do I ask the model to wait for all validations before inserting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing custom validator arity (the second argument is a callback) you can change it to an asynchronous handler. So your code should look like this:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Step = sequelize.define('Step', {
  ...
  resultDate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    validate: {
      isEven(value, next){
        sequelize.models.Call
          .findById(this.call_id)
          .then(call => {
            next(value >= call.endingDate ? 'Error message here!' : null)
          })
          .catch(next);
  ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the "Step" model in the "isEven" validation?